# Jersey: Get binary data from post request

Tags: java, jersey

I am trying to build a Java server using Jersey, which accepts POST requests with binary data.

Here is a sample request it should accept:

```
curl -XPOST --data-binary @/path/to/some/file "localhost:<port>/myServer/processMyData"
```

I implemented something that currently doesn't work:

```
@Path("/myServer")
class MyServer {

    @POST
    @Path("/processMyData")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    String processMyData(byte[] payload) {
        return "Sanity check string";
    }
}
```

When I run the `curl` command (see above) at the first time, I get the error:

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Then, curl prints nothing when I call it again, and exits with status 0, while the server ignores everything.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Note: When I remove the `--data-binary @/path/to/some/file` clause from the `curl` command, the request is accepted on the server. How can I accept the binary data in Jersey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself...

It is very simple, the removal of `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)` solved the problem